# Log work effort without full timestamp in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Using emacs I'm trying to find a way to log some work effort for each task without specifying the full timestamp. For example, I want to able to say that I've spent 2h on task1 and 4h on task2 on day1, 3h on task1 and 2h on task3 on day2 etc without specifying the exact times. Additionaly, if I could get a task wise report at the end of the week about effort spent on each task in that week, that helps a lot.

I've tried org-clock-in and org-clock-out (C-c C-x C-i/o), but they require full timestamp. Is there any built-in way/feature I could use for my requirement without any custom emacs lisp?